# How to make LR waiting only time needed?

Tags: load-testing, loadrunner

Our application perfoms the query and then selects on of the results. I would like to automate this in order to measure the system overload, but the main problem I have is: the more users, the longer it takes for backend to return the results. Hence I need loadrunner to perform the query and then perform the action as soon as the results have been returned. Or does LR do this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LoadRunner will wait until the time specified in client timeout automaticallyb before entering into an error state.   If you have no wait time between your query and your next statement and your query finishes within your client timeout window, then loadrunner will continue automatically with your next statement a soon as the current statement is complete.

This is a question normally covered in training.  If not in training then as a part of your post training mentoring/internship period.